# What happens to the Meister when they complete a Death Scythe?

Tags: soul-eater

The Soul Eater anime only mentions one Meister who created a Death Scythe, and that was Maka's mother with Spirit Albarn being the Death Scythe she created.

When the other Death Weapons arrived in Death City after Asura's release, we did find out that the Death Scythes were stationed around the world. However, the anime didn't reveal who their Meisters were, or even what happened to them.

So I am wondering: What happens to a Meister when their Weapon Partner becomes a Death Scythe? Would the process be different with Kid and the Thompson Sisters? (Kid stated that he would rather use a Death Scythe he made than one of his father's)

Answer (score 2):

In the anime, Maka's mom is referenced many times by Maka, who says that she occasionally gets postcards from places her mother has been to. Therefore, I'm assuming that after a Meister makes a Death Scythe, they take on a job like any other person would, or maybe some special mission from Lord Death himself. After all, after the Weapons become Scythes, they go around the world protecting different parts of the world.

This is just a theory. The answer may have been revealed in the manga, but I don't know for certain. I hope this helped a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

The Meisters who made their Weapons into Death Scythes are then ready to take on evil with their Meister abilities like Stein. They probably become a backup plan when Satan-sama or Shinigami-sama aren't available or incapable of using the Death Scythe. I can't understand why there are so many Death Scythes who are used by the Shinigami only. There has to be more than just the Shinigami who can use them in times of need.

Another logical explanation would be that the Meister who upgrades the Weapon into a Death Scythe is probably its best user, so they are probably only summoned when needed. However, many Death Scythes who operate on their own (like Justin) can be used even when Shinigami or Meister aren't available. Until they are summoned, the Meisters probably have to take on some jobs for survival, etc. However, they might be summoned to use the Weapons that they have converted to Death Scythe because of their mastery and wavelength compatibilities. This can be observed when all the Death Scythes that Crona destroyed were accompanied with their Meisters at the place.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Spirit is the only personal Death Scythe and none of the others are supposed to be used by death. The other's probably were trained by themselves or a meister who left. Like how Marie keeps on talking about partners that left her. It is also posible that the death's scythes can connect to multiple wavelength and are able to go between multiple parters like Stein or I am over thinking this and the animators did not come up with an explanation.

Answer (score -2):

I've seen something online that led me to believe that the meister in exception of Maka's parents follows their partners. I haven't seen anything about Marie or Azusa, but I've seen it in the other cases.

Justin Law is just a badass and can do it on his own so he's exempted, but the other 4 should have some info on it.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Could you try to find and mention the source of this (whether the online link, or chapter# / episode#)? We discourage answers that can't be backed up by some references.